# TYPOSCRIPT: Overriding multiple times

Tags: image, overriding, typo3, typoscript

I have 3 images (content Objects):

```
tempProjectImage = IMAGE                                                                  
                tempProjectImage {
                    file{
                        #Nur der erste Eintrag.
                        import.listNum = 0

                        #Datei wird aus DAM gelesen
                        import.cObject = USER                               
                        import.cObject {
                            userFunc = tx_dam_tsfe->fetchFileList
                            refField = project_picture
                            refTable = tx_nmshowroom_items
                        }                            
                        width = 298
                        height = 200                            
                    }

                    altText.field = title
                    titleText.field = title
                    params = class="previewImage"                                                                                                       
                }

tempItemImage = IMAGE                                                                  
                tempItemImage {
                    file{
                        #Nur der erste Eintrag.
                        import.listNum = 0

                        #Datei wird aus DAM gelesen
                        import.cObject = USER                               
                        import.cObject {
                            userFunc = tx_dam_tsfe->fetchFileList
                            refField = images
                            refTable = tx_nmshowroom_items
                        }                            
                        width = 298
                        height = 200                            
                    }

                    altText.field = title
                    titleText.field = title
                    params = class="previewImage"                                                                                                       
                }

custImage = IMAGE
                    custImage {
                        file{
                            #Nur der erste Eintrag.
                            import.listNum = 0

                            #Datei wird aus DAM gelesen
                            import.cObject = USER                               
                            import.cObject = USER                               
                            import.cObject {
                                userFunc = tx_dam_tsfe->fetchFileList
                                refField = images
                                refTable = tx_nmshowroom_customers
                                refUid.field = tx_nmshowroom_customers
                            }                        
                            width = 298
                            height = 200                            
                        }

                        altText.field = title
                        titleText.field = title
                        params = class="previewImage"                                                                                                       
                    }
```

In my HTML Template I have

```
###IMAGE###
```

What I want to do is a sort of multiple override:

If tempItemImage is empty then display tempProjectImage and if tempProjectImage is also empty, then display custImage.

I started with:

```
image < .customers.custImage
image.file.import.override.cObject < .tempProjectImage.file.import.cObject
```

And this works perfectly. But when I add another override:

```
image < .customers.custImage
image.file.import.override.cObject < .tempProjectImage.file.import.cObject
image.file.import.override.cObject < .tempItemImage.file.import.cObject
```

It does not work anymore. tempItemImage (if present) will never override the other images.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Davide

Comment: Is this maybe a wrong approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a stdWrap function "ifEmpty", i guess that fits to what you want to do.

(untested)

```
# you need only one IMAGE object,
# but you add an ifEmpty statement, two times with
# the fall back USER-Object
tempProjectImage = IMAGE                                                                  
tempProjectImage {
  file{
    import.listNum = 0
    import.cObject = USER                               
    import.cObject {
      # default
    }
    import.ifEmpty.cObject = USER
    import.ifEmpty.cObject {
       # Fallback 
    }
    import.ifEmpty.ifEmpty.cObject = USER
    import.ifEmpty.ifEmpty.cObject {
       # second fallback
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just 4 words: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!